# JSON environnement variable is seen as a string

Tags: json, node.js, environment-variables, nodemailer

I'm trying to help a friend about his nodejs application.
He use NodeMailer to send emails automatically. We both use ubuntu.

To avoid any leaks, the credential for NodeMailer are set as an environnement variable called `EMAIL_CREDENTIALS`.

In the app, EMAIL_CREDENTIAL is called as follow:

```
 var emailCredentials = process.env.EMAIL_CREDENTIALS;
 if (emailCredentials === 'undefined') {
   throw Error('Email credentials are not present');
 }
 // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(emailCredentials);
```

To set email credential I added a line in `src/environnement` :

```
 EMAIL_CREDENTIALS={host:"smtp.gmail.com", port: 587, secure: false, auth: {user: "**user**", pass: "**pass**"}}
```

When I run some test, NodeMailer return the following error

```
 Error: Unsupported configuration, downgrade Nodemailer to v0.7.1 to use it
     at Nodemailer.sendMail (/home/**path**/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js:274:18)
```

This error happen because `type of param === 'string'` in `nodemailer.createTransport(param)` .

My friend has been using this code for a pretty long time with no problem.

Somehow, I understand where the error come from but I would like to know how is it possible that the environnement variable of my friends setup isn't a string and mine is ? And how should I set my variable to be able to run his code without modifying it ?

EDIT: To use JSON.parse() would be a solution but I would prefer not to modifie the app code and as I said this configuration seems to work for my friend so I would like to understand where's the difference.

Comment: how do you require the `src/environment` ? if it tell you it's a string, temporarily use console.log to debug it. you might need json parse.

Comment: Have you tried using `JSON.parse(process.env.EMAIL_CREDENTIALS)` instead of directly using the value? I believe that environment variables are just simple strings.

Comment: when I use json.parse I have `unexpected character 'h' at position 1`. 
....... now that I think about it it's probably because `host` should be surrounded with comma.
Otherwise, the point is that I don't want to modifie the code because the code is not mine and is supposed to work for my friend...
I'll run some test.

Comment: Well JSON.parse works well but as said before I'm not satisfied with this solution.

Comment: Well I think you should not use environment variables like this. I will post an answer on how to do it other way.

Comment: Btw are you and your friend on same platform? There might be differences among macox/win/linux in this. AFAIK on linux/mac, the variable is just plain string...

Comment: both on linux ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better not to use environment variables for other than simple values. I would suggest you to use a plain JS or JSON file with those variables, that you can simple `require()`. You can ignore this file via .gitignore, if you do not want it to be included in a git repository.

You can take a look at my configuration module here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mikro-config

It is designed to be used this way.

Using it, your general configuration will be stored in `/config/default.js` file, and your environment specific configuration will be stored in `/config/env/$NODE_ENV.js` file (or in `/config/env/$NODE_ENV.local.js`, which should be ignored by git, as I described above).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think that it's a good alternative solution.